# ASP.NET Webforms - Displaying HTML content from a WYSIWYG editor as is without bootstrap styles from Master Page interfering

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

In ASP.NET Webforms I have a Master Page where bootstrap css is imported. All of the child pages of the site use this Master Page.

One of the child pages displays HTML content originally created in a WYSIWYG editor. Since this child pages uses the master page and relies on it so the header and footer match everything else the styles override the WYSIWYG content styles.

Is there a way I can make it so a section of the page ignores bootstrap even though it is being imported from the master page but the rest of the page like the header and footer still use it?

Trying to avoid separating this page from using the Master Page.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible method I can think of would be to create a custom css file for this page, and create specific css classes for each element that will override the css imported from the bootstrap via masterpage.